# How to lookup a non-jta-data-source/jta-data-source via a Webservice

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee, jpa, websphere-7

I get the following error when my Webservice is invoked:

```
org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: A JDBC Driver or DataSource class name must be specified in the ConnectionDriverName property.
```

The Webservice class is bascially trying to use JPA to insert data, and based on the above error message it seems the EntityManager cant access the datasource entry as shown below:

```
<persistence-unit name="TEST_P" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL"> 
        <provider>
        com.ibm.websphere.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl
        </provider>
        <non-jta-data-source>java:comp/env/jdbc/DATA</non-jta-data-source>
        <class>jpa.WSTGHandler</class>
            <properties>

        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
```

I have also defined the datasource entry in the web.xml as shown below:

```
      <resource-ref>
        <res-ref-name>java:comp/env/jdbc/DATA</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
        <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
    </resource-ref>
```

Embedding the JPA code in In Servlet suceesfully locates the datasource. how can I get the Webservice to work the same way ?

PS: I am using Websphere 7, JPA version 1.2, and JAX-WS

As requested, the follwing class is invoked int he Webservice method i.e beginTransaction()

```
public class EntityManagerHelper {

    private static final EntityManagerFactory emf; 
    private static final ThreadLocal<EntityManager> threadLocal;
    private static final Logger logger;

    static {
        emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("TEST_P");         
        threadLocal = new ThreadLocal<EntityManager>();
        logger = Logger.getLogger("TEST_P");
        logger.setLevel(Level.FINE);
    }

    public static EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        EntityManager manager = threadLocal.get();      
        if (manager == null || !manager.isOpen()) {
            manager = emf.createEntityManager();
            threadLocal.set(manager);
        }
        return manager;
    }

     public static void closeEntityManager() {
        EntityManager em = threadLocal.get();
        threadLocal.set(null);
        if (em != null) em.close();
    }

    public static void beginTransaction() {
        getEntityManager().getTransaction().begin();
    }

    public static void commit() {
        getEntityManager().getTransaction().commit();
    }  

    public static void rollback() {
        getEntityManager().getTransaction().rollback();
    } 

    public static Query createQuery(String query) {
        return getEntityManager().createQuery(query);
    }

    public static void log(String info, Level level, Throwable ex) {
        logger.log(level, info, ex);
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you add JPA code for data insertion, from where the exception occurs

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved. it was just a typo in the res-ref-name :)